# Made Locust to login to a Web Application

Tags: locust

I want locust to be able to login to my web application and start to click in the links inside the web application.

With this code I just get activity for the front page with the login and i don't get any notification from inside the application.

Code:

```
import random
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
from pyquery import PyQuery


class WalkPages(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.client.post("/", {
            "UserName": "my@email.com",
            "Password": "2Password!",
            "submit": "Sign In"
        })
       self.index_page()

    @task(10)
    def index_page(self):
        r = self.client.get("/Dashboard.mvc")
        pq = PyQuery(r.content)
        link_elements = pq("a")
        self.urls_on_current_page = []
        for l in link_elements:
          if "href" in l.attrib:
            self.urls_on_current_page.append(l.attrib["href"])

    @task(30)
    def load_page(self):
        url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
        r = self.client.get(url)


class AwesomeUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = WalkPages
    host = "https://myenv.beta.webapp.com"
    min_wait = 20  * 1000
    max_wait = 60  * 1000
```

I get the follow msg in the terminal after the first round.

```
[2015-02-13 12:08:43,740] webapp-qa/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 267, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 293, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(task["callable"], *task["args"], **task["kwargs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 305, in execute_task
    task(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/webapp/LoadTest/locustfile.py", line 31, in load_page
    url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 273, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
[2015-02-13 12:08:43,752] webapp-qa/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 267, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 293, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(task["callable"], *task["args"], **task["kwargs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 305, in execute_task
    task(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/webapp/LoadTest/locustfile.py", line 31, in load_page
    url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 273, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
[2015-02-13 12:08:43,775] webapp-qa/ERROR/stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 267, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 293, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(task["callable"], *task["args"], **task["kwargs"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/locust/core.py", line 305, in execute_task
    task(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/webapp/LoadTest/locustfile.py", line 31, in load_page
    url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 273, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The part `       self.index_page()` doesn't look indented correctly. Also, you try bringing in the index_page logic inside the on_startup function.

Comment: Let me change the logic of the on_startup, Thanks for your review.

Answer (score 0):

Your list may be empty.

```
@task(30)
def load_page(self):
    if self.urls_on_current_page:
        url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
        r = self.client.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I takes time but someone may need this. My findings in your code: **login** requests seems not correct (check mine if correct), you cannot reach a variable defined inside of a function from another function, giving `task(10)` is not suitable for data **setter function**. Set urls_on_current_page as a class variable to serve for other class members. See my code and comment:

```
import random
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
from pyquery import PyQuery


class WalkPages(TaskSet):
    # define variable here to access them from inside the functions
    urls_on_current_page = []

    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/login", data = {"UserName": "mesutgunes@email.com", "Password": "password"})

    def get_urls(self):
        r = self.client.get("/Dashboard.mvc")
        pq = PyQuery(r.content)
        link_elements = pq("a")
        for link in link_elements:
            if key in link.attrib and "http" not in link.attrib[key]: 
            # there maybe external link on the page
                self.urls_on_current_page.append(link.attrib[key])


    def on_start(self):
        self.login()
        self.get_urls()


    @task(30)
    def load_page(self):
        url = random.choice(self.urls_on_current_page)
        r = self.client.get(url)


class AwesomeUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = WalkPages
    host = "https://myenv.beta.webapp.com"
    min_wait = 20  * 1000 
    max_wait = 60  * 1000
```